# Products are not shown if the user is not logged in

Tags: python, django, mezzanine, cartridge

I am trying to develop a small project to learn how mezzanine and cartridge work.

I have the problem that items in the shop are listed only if I am logged in, while I'd like to be able to show them to unauthorized users.

Is there a setting that has to be toggled?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The products most likely aren't published, but can be previewed by an authenticated administrator.

Check the "status" and "published from" fields for each product.

Comment: It must have been a time issue, I anticipated the "published from" of one day, and it worked. Thank you